# How to extract data out of a specific PHP array

Tags: php

I have a multi-dimensional array that looks like this: 
The base array is indexed based on category ids from my catalog.

```
$cat[category_id]
```

Each base array has three underlying elements:

```
['parent_id']
['sort_order']
['name']
```

I want to create a function that allows us to create a list of category_id's and names for a given parent_category_id in the correct sort order.  Is this possible?  Technically it is the same information, but the array is constructed in a weird way to extract that information.

Here is an example definition for the array:

```
$cat = array();
$cat[32]['parent_id']= 0;
$cat[32]['sort_order']= 1;
$cat[32]['name']= 'my-category-name1';
$cat[45]['parent_id']= 0;
$cat[45]['sort_order']= 0;
$cat[45]['name']= 'my-category-name2';
$cat[2]['parent_id']= 0;
$cat[2]['sort_order']= 2;
$cat[2]['name'] = "my-category-name3";
$cat[3]['parent_id']= 2;
$cat[3]['sort_order']= 1;
$cat[3]['name'] = "my-category-name4";
$cat[6]['parent_id']= 2;
$cat[6]['sort_order']= 0;
$cat[6]['name'] = "my-category-name5";
```

Comment: If sort_order is numeric and unique for any set of categories at the same level in the heirarchy, use that to index the array... Otherwise this is a standard recursive parent->child array building.

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete example of your array? (best with `var_export`).

Comment: Arrays and array functionality in PHP are very flexible. However, I don't understand your array structure. Can you print_r() your array? If you put the output between a pre tag, it would show up very nicely:

    <pre><?php print_r($yourArray); ?></pre>

Comment: @ChristianSciberras: `<?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($yourArray,1).'<pre>';?>` seems more elegant, no? ;-)

Comment: @Brad - But more code intensive, and less IDE-friendly (the IDE can't know about the pre inside the string ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's something of this sort:

```
$ary = Array(
  0 => Array(
    'parent_category_id' => null,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'name' => 'my-category-name0'
  ),
  1 => Array(
    'parent_category_id' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 1,
    'name' => 'my-category-name1'
  ),
  2 => Array(
    'parent_category_id' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 2,
    'name' => 'my-category-name2'
  ),
  3 => Array(
    'parent_category_id' => null,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'name' => 'my-category-name3'
  ),
  4 => Array(
    'parent_category_id' => 3,
    'sort_order' => 0,
    'name' => 'my-category-name4'
  )
);
```

You can use a combination of a foreach and [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to achieve what you're going for.

```
// @array: the array you're searchign through
// @parent_id: the parent id you're filtering by
function getFromParent($array, $parent_id){
  $result = Array();
  foreach ($array as $category_id => $entry){
    if ($entry['parent_category_id']===$parent_id)
      $result[$category_id] = $entry;
  }
  usort($result,create_function('$a,$b','return ($a["sort_order"]>$b["sort_order"]?1:($b["sort_order"]<$a["sort_order"]?-1:0));'));
  return $result;
}

var_export(getFromParent($ary,0));
```

**EDIT** Sorry, fixed some syntax errors. Tested, and works (at least to result in what I was intending)
**EDITv2** Here's the raw output from the above:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'parent_category_id' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 1,
    'name' => 'my-category-name1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'parent_category_id' => 0,
    'sort_order' => 2,
    'name' => 'my-category-name2',
  ),
)
```

(Used var_export just for you @FelixKling)

**EDITv3** I've updated my answer to go along with the OP's update. I also now make it retain the original "category_id" values in the result array.

Answer (score 0):

First you create an empty array, it will be used to store your result.

```
$result = array();
```

You need to iterate through your initial array, you can use `foreach()`.

Then, given your `parent_category_id` simply use an `if` statement to check whether it's the given id or not.

If it is, just construct and push your result to your `$result` array.

Use any of the [sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) you like

Use the magic `return $result;`

You're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnSortedParents($categories, $target_parent){

    $new_list = array();

    foreach($categories as $index => $array){
        //FIND ONLY THE ELEMENTS MATCHING THE TARGET PARENT ID 
        if($array['parent_category_id']==$target_parent){ 
            $new_list[$index = $array['sort_order'];
        }

    return asort($new_list);  //SORT BASED ON THE VALUES, WHICH IS THE SORTING ORDER
}
```