# how to read data in array?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract data out of a specific PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927843/how-to-extract-data-out-of-a-specific-php-array)

I have an array that I am trying to fetch all elements from a specific key in. The key is `shard3`.
The result should be `'user'=>'root','password'=>'3', 'db'=>'test', 'port'=>3307`

```
    private   $shard_list = array ( 
      'shard1' => array( 'host'=>'127.0.0.1',
     'user'=>'root',
     'password'=>'1',
     'db'=>'test', 
     'port'=>3306
    ),
    'shard2' => array( 'host'=>'127.0.0.2',
        'user'=>'root',
        'password'=>'2',
         'db'=>'test', 
         'port'=>3307
     ),
     'shard3' => array( 'host'=>'127.0.0.3',
     'user'=>'root',
     'password'=>'3',
     'db'=>'test', 
     'port'=>3307
     ),
    'shard4' => array( 'host'=>'127.0.0.4',
        'user'=>'root',
        'password'=>'4',
         'db'=>'test', 
        'port'=>3307
     )
```

I want to read all elements in `shard3`. What is the way to read all elements?

Comment: Please read the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) before asking that.

Comment: and read suggestions on your right...

Comment: $data = $shard_list['shard3'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you're defining it in a class. Because you're defining it as a `private` property, you cannot access it outside of your class. If you need to access it from the outer scope, use the getter method.

To access it from within the class, you can simply do `$this->shard_list['shard3']`, as  Dan suggests.

In case you do need to access it from the outer scope, and you don't want to set the property to `public`, define a 'getter' method like this:

```
public function getShard_list()
{

return $this->shard_list;

}
```

The function above should sit in your class.

And then call it from the outer scope:

```
$shardList = $myClassInstance->getShard_list();

print_r( $shardList['shard3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before answering, I would recommend to start reading basic PHP functionality.

As for this question, since you have `private` before your variable, I am assuming this is a property inside a class of yours, you can access it by using `$this->shard_list['shard3']`.

Comment: NEVER link to that site! http://w3fools.com/